# warning Build settings in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i am facing some warnings in build settings

- adopt "Product bundle identifier" build setting
- turn on "Enable testability" when debugging

how to proceed...

[image]

Comment: just proceed with '**Perform Changes**'.